# HTML CSS Table displays rows at bottom instead of the top of the table

Tags: html, html-table, sass

I am trying to finish formatting a table that is built dynamically.  On the last page, when the table is sparse because there are fewer than the rows needed to fill the table, the rows are displayed at the bottom of the table space instead of the top.  I've tried to correct this unsuccessfully.  How can I display these rows at the top?

It doesn't seem to matter, but the table is built by the will_paginate Ruby gem.  I say it doesn't matter because when I look at the HTML, it's just a table.  There is nothing in there that is making this happen.  The table size is formatted to display 10 rows.  If there are only 3, they are just listed as 3 rows as you would expect.  So, I think it is just an HTML/CSS formatting question.

The Table as it displays:
[image: Show the table has it displays]

The SCSS:

```
.feeds {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 700px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  li {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid $grayLighter;
    &:last-child {
      border-bottom: 1px solid $grayLighter;
    }
  }
  table, thead, th, tr, tbody, tfoot {
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  td {
    vertical-align:top;
    height: 1ex;
    overflow-x: auto
  }
}
```

The HTML:

```
    <table class="feeds">
      <tbody><tr>
        <th id="url_cell"><a class="sortfield asc" href="/feeds?commit=Search&amp;direction=desc&amp;search=&amp;sort=feed_url&amp;utf8=%E2%9C%93">URL</a></th>
        <th><a href="/feeds?commit=Search&amp;direction=asc&amp;search=&amp;sort=feed_etag&amp;utf8=%E2%9C%93">Etag</a></th>
        <th><a href="/feeds?commit=Search&amp;direction=asc&amp;search=&amp;sort=feed_update&amp;utf8=%E2%9C%93">Update date</a></th>
      </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="url_cell"><a href="http://www.skalith.net/rss">http://www.skalith.net/rss</a></td>
            <td id="etag_cell">RZWAFDMVHPXHWECK</td>
            <td id="update_cell">August  5, 2013</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="url_cell"><a href="http://www.viva.name/rss">http://www.viva.name/rss</a></td>
            <td id="etag_cell">KFIEQYAUWMUHUJNY</td>
            <td id="update_cell">August  5, 2013</td>
          </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Comment: The height setting of your .feeds class is dictating the size of the table and therefore how the <tr>'s are rendered. You could work around that by removing that attribute and either resizing/padding the <tr>'s or adding trailing padding after the table.

Comment: Also, either tag your question SCSS instead of CSS, or provide just CSS in place of SCSS.

Comment: Adding the extra rows worked as a quick way of solving it, too.

Comment: I changed the tag from CSS to SCSS three times now.  I verified it said SCSS.  It keeps coming up SASS...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The header row is filling out the space vertically (this is what it should do because of your `table-layout`.  If you wrap it with `<thead>` and then only wrap the body of the table with `<tbody>` it will align it correctly. However, because you have `table-layout: fixed`, with `height: 250px`, the remaining rows will grow to make up the difference.

See: http://codepen.io/chrisrockwell/pen/gGmFq

Can you add a class to the table if it doesn't have a full set of rows? This way you could remove the height declaration.

Other options:

1. I'm guessing you need to have a set height but, if not, you could remove it.
2. Wrap the table in a `<div>` and assign your height and overflow to the div:

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <table class="feeds"></table>
</div>
```

```
.wrap {
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}
table {
  /* just remove the height and overflow */
}
```

Here is an example of Option 2: http://codepen.io/chrisrockwell/pen/wpyfI

Comment: I do need a fixed height to keep the page format consistent.  These changes were perfect using option 2.  I really appreciate your work in CodePen to show it to me.  Thanks....